# Pushing Array value to first Index

Tags: javascript

```
var Config = {
   Windows: ['apple','mangi','lemon']
}
```

I have a condition and based on that i want to Push the banana value in my Array.

```
If(Condition Passed) {
      Config.Windows.unshift('banana');
      Windows: ['banana','apple','mangi','lemon']
      Config.Windows.reverse();
      // The way the Array elements are now reversed and First banana is accessed. 
    } else { 
      Config.Windows.reverse();     
}
```

It does not do it... when i use the Config.Windows in my other function there is no `banana` Value... at all

```
for each(var item in Config.Windows.reverse()) {
 Ti.API.info(item);
 //This does not print banana
```

Comment: The `unshift` is not supported by IE so if that's your browser it explains why it's not working.

Comment: FYI: `for each` is a Mozilla construct. It will not work in any other browser.

Comment: `unshift` *is* supported in IE, but does not return the length of the new array unlike in other browsers (thanks to [Jon's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13280099/141881) for pointing this out)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can push the value to the front of the array. Immediately, I can think of two ways:

- Create a new array, and replace the old one

  ```
  if (condition) {
      Config.Windows = ['banana'].join(Config.Windows)
      Config.Windows.reverse();
  } else {
      Config.Windows.reverse();
  }
  ```
- Based on what you've said, it would make more sense to always reverse the array, then push your value:

  ```
  //initial array: ['apple','mangi','lemon']

  Config.Windows.reverse(); //['lemon','mangi','apple']
  if (condition) {
      //this will get the same result as your code
      Config.Windows.push("banana"); //['lemon','mangi','apple', 'banana']
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

"The unshift is not supported by IE so if that's your browser it explains why it's not working. "

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ezk94dwt(v=vs.94).aspx